# PhpStorm does not sync with the server

Tags: phpstorm

Here's the problem :

My project on phpStorm use a remote access to the server by FTP.
When I save a modified file, the file is uploaded normally to the serv, but when I create a folder on the serv, i don't see it in phpStorm.

Any idea?

Comment: Like... at all? Even on manually refresh?

Comment: If by "manually refresh" you mean the "Synchronize" function of phpStorm, yep

Comment: **1)** Which "Synchronize"? Can you please show a screenshot with that button (highlight it with red color or something). **2)** Where do you expect to see your remote folder appeared -- as I understand in Project View?

Comment: 1) Here's the screen: http://hpics.li/babc392

Comment: 2) I expect to see the folder I created on the serv here, into the html folder : http://hpics.li/a309599

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**PhpStorm is built around "local project files are the main ones -- deployed are secondary" idea.** It's natural to have "automatically upload to remote host" (sync local with remote) functionality to follow such an idea.

At the same time the IDE does not have anything to "*automatically* sync remote with local" (the reverse: to *automatically* copy remote stuff back to local). Simply because it contradicts such an idea: local files are the main ones.

#### Therefore:

**The "Synchronize" button that you are referring to** does not do what you are expecting it to do. It syncs what the IDE knows about project files on a local file system. In other words: it checks if there were any changes to local files done outside of the IDE. *It does not do anything with **remote** files.*

**NOTE:** In modern 202x.x versions it has been renamed to "Reload All from Disk" to avoid such a confusion).

**To manually sync with remote files (any direction)** you have these main options:

- Use **`Remote Host`** side panel (can be accessed via `Tools | Deployment | Browse Remote Host` if it’s closed/hidden) and download any files or folders manually (drag and drop can also be used, just make sure that you are copying files because by default IDE tries to "move" (copy+delete) instead of just "copy"). It has a "Refresh" button to refresh the remote location.
- Use **two-way synchronisation (with preview)** accessible via right click on desired folder(s)/files and choosing `Deployment | Synch with Deployed...` where you can sync those files/folders both ways (by default newer stuff will override older regardless of the direction).

**The IDE can automatically sync one way (from local to remote):** just ensure that automatic deployment is enabled and you have one server (or a group) marked as Default for this project.

`Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Deployment | Options | Upload changed files automatically to the default server` is the option. Check other options there to better suit your needs.

[image]

Please refer to the official help pages for more info on deployment (including a simple video tutorial): https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/deploying-applications.html

Comment: Oh, didn't know phpStorm had a FTP navigator. Thanks !

Comment: I've been wondering about this for ages; excellent explanation, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

And the funny thing about it, it is not completly correct. The option underneath is missing.. 'skip external changes' should not be ticked.
In Mac -> PHPStorm -> preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> options
Set the Upload as seen in the picture to always and make sure skip external changes is unticked.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me in PhpStorm 2020.1

[image: PhpStorm settings showing "Upload changed files automatically to the default server"]

Comment: In addition to the image a text description of how to access settings and how to find this setting within settings would improve this answer. When adding an answer to a five year old question with an accepted answer it is important to point out what new aspect of the question your answer addresses.