# Cannot get PHP Storm to compare deployed files with local

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm, synchronization, remote-server

I have a directory on my server which has been changed - files and folders added. I want to sync this with the local directory and I cannot get it to work.

This question pretty much covers the problem but the solution hasn't worked for me: [PhpStorm does not sync with the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26231260/phpstorm-does-not-sync-with-the-server)

I right click on the local directory and choose `deployment > sync with deployed`. It brings up a window to compare differences but then says there is nothing to show.

But by browsing the remote host I can see there are a large number of differences. Changing the `compare by` filter from content to size, or size and timestamp makes no difference.

Comment: You are following a completely wrong approach. Start using a revision control system like `svn` or `git` and _never_ somehow directly push files between your IDE and your server space. Instead use a repository as exchange relay. Commit your local changes you made and publish them by pulling a new version from the repository to the server space. If somehow the files on the server space got changed (how can that happen?), then you can compare or even commit those changes the other way 'round.

Comment: Screenshots please. Also -- [enable extra logging](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-1202) and provide logs (in case there is errors/exceptions there). Please also make sure that you are using correct deployment entry and you are mapping to correct folder -- quite likely that you are trying to sync wrong folder.